# Text file update to in sql server in real time

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, ssis, wmi

I have an requirement. I have a text file.

data will be dump into that file always.

Whenever there is an update in that text file . The same should update in SQL Server as well.

Is that possible??

SQL agent jobs with integration service packages is not recommended .. any other way.

Comment: whats the reason for this in  your question _SQL agent jobs with integration service packages is not recommended .. any other way._

Comment: I've added the WMI tag to your question - someone might be able to help there. Why put an SSIS tag on it if you don't want to use SSIS?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own f.ex. .NET application / windows service with file watchdog and monitor file content changes.

EDIT:
In SSIS you can also try to use File Watcher Task:
[Handling file access locks while file is being built](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516820/handling-file-access-locks-while-file-is-being-built)

Out of curiosity, why using SSIS and SQL Server Agent is not recommended?

Comment: Data is real time.. Connected to different application

Comment: So file is actually locked all the time? Is this what you mean?